# WPF window state when restored from maximized gets stuck in odd state

Tags: wpf, window

I'm seeing some strange behaviour from WPF. I have a form with three buttons on it. One button should make the window fullscreen, one should center it on the monitor its currently on, the third button should restore the window to its normal position.

The XAML is

```
<Window x:Class="TestRestore.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestRestore"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Max" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Click="max_click" Name="max_button"/>
        <Button Content="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Click="center_click" Name="center_button"/>
        <Button Content="Restore" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="227,143,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="restore_click" Name="restore_button" IsEnabled="False"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the code is below. The strange behaviour is that when I maximize, and then restore the window, the position is correctly restored but the window still thinks it's maximized (the maximize button looks like a restore button and you can't resize the window even though ResizeMode has been set to CanResizeWithGrip).

When the maximized window has been restored, and it thinks its still maximized even though the window position isn't maximized, just moving the window manually by dragging the title bar is enough to cause it to correct itself back to non-maximized mode.

Also, if I maximize then restore the window and then maximize it again without moving it, the maximized window position is incorrect (not in the top left).

And the mystery deepens. If I maximize then restore the window, then press alt, then press down (to get the window menu) and select 'Move' and then move the window around with the keyboard, it stays stuck in 'bogus not-mazimized mode' even though the window is being moved, so it seems the only way to unstick it is to move it with the mouse.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace TestRestore
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        WindowStyle old_window_style;
        WindowState old_window_state;
        double old_left;
        double old_top;
        double old_width;
        double old_height;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // remember position, style and state
        private void SaveWindowPos()
        {
            old_window_style = WindowStyle;
            old_window_state = WindowState;
            old_left = Left;
            old_top = Top;
            old_width = Width;
            old_height = Height;
            max_button.IsEnabled = false;
            center_button.IsEnabled = false;
            restore_button.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        // put position, style and state back
        private void RestoreWindowPos()
        {
            WindowStyle = old_window_style;
            WindowState = old_window_state;
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip;
            Left = old_left;
            Top = old_top;
            Width = old_width;
            Height = old_height;
            max_button.IsEnabled = true;
            center_button.IsEnabled = true;
            restore_button.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        // make it centered or fullscreen
        private void SetActivePos(bool full_screen)
        {
            SaveWindowPos();
            Hide();
            if (full_screen)
            {
                ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
                WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            }
            else
            {
                Size s = new Size(800, 600);
                Point p = CenterRectInMonitor(this, s);
                Left = p.X;
                Top = p.Y;
                Width = s.Width;
                Height = s.Height;
                ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
                WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            }
            Show();
        }

        private void restore_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Hide();
            RestoreWindowPos();
            Show();
        }

        private void max_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetActivePos(true);
        }

        private void center_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetActivePos(false);
        }

        // interop

        public const Int32 MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY = 0x00000001;
        public const Int32 MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 0x00000002;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr MonitorFromWindow(IntPtr handle, Int32 flags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor, ref MonitorInfoEx lpmi);

        // size of a device name string
        private const int CCHDEVICENAME = 32;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct MonitorInfoEx
        {
            public int Size;
            public RectStruct Monitor;
            public RectStruct WorkArea;
            public uint Flags;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCHDEVICENAME)]
            public string DeviceName;

            public void Init()
            {
                this.Size = 40 + 2 * CCHDEVICENAME;
                this.DeviceName = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RectStruct
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;

            public int Width
            {
                get
                {
                    return Right - Left;
                }
            }

            public int Height
            {
                get
                {
                    return Bottom - Top;
                }
            }
        }

        public static MonitorInfoEx GetMonitorFromWindow(Window w)
        {
            var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(w).EnsureHandle();
            var monitor = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
            MonitorInfoEx monitor_info = new MonitorInfoEx();
            monitor_info.Init();
            GetMonitorInfo(monitor, ref monitor_info);
            return monitor_info;
        }

        // work out how a rect of 'Size size' should be centered on the monitor containing 'Window w'
        public static Point CenterRectInMonitor(Window w, Size size)
        {
            var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(w);
            double x_scale = source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;
            double y_scale = source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22;
            var width = size.Width * x_scale;
            var height = size.Height * y_scale;
            var monitor_info = GetMonitorFromWindow(w);
            Size s = new Size(monitor_info.Monitor.Width, monitor_info.Monitor.Height);
            Point p = new Point(monitor_info.Monitor.Left, monitor_info.Monitor.Top);
            Point c = new Point(p.X + s.Width / 2, p.Y + s.Height / 2);
            return new Point((c.X - width / 2) / x_scale, (c.Y - height / 2) / y_scale);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer for you.  However you will find that your code starts working a lot better once you remove the Hide() and Show() calls.

```
    private void restore_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
//            Hide();
        RestoreWindowPos();
//            Show();
    }
```

I'm sure you put this in to reduce flicker, but what I think is happening is that the Hide() and Show() calls are flipping the WS_VISIBLE bit in the window style word of the underlying OS window which is the same word which contains the WS_MAXIMIZE and WS_BORDER and some other things that you are manipulating.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx

It would take more research to figure out what is exactly going on, but the fundamental problem I believe is a "leaky abstraction".  Your code sets top, left, style and state as if these were independent uncoupled variables. But they are not!  To set left, the OS SetWindowPos() function must be called which requires not the upper left coordinate, the window size, the Z order as well as visibility flags and whether the windows is maximized! See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx.  So each time you set one of these "independent" variables you are pounding SetWindowPos().  This API call harks back to the bad old days when CPU cycles were precious and you need to pack as much functionality as possible into each API call.

Ironically this is making your code very inefficient.  I think the thing to do to straighten this out is to bypass the leaking abstraction of System.Windows.Window and call SetWindowPos and possibility other API functions directly from user32.dll.  Then things will be a lot more predicable.

Comment: Thanks, removing Hide() and Show() fixes it. They were in there to fix a previous problem to do with setting the WindowState but removing them doesn't seem to have caused that to come back.