# User Control Not Resizing When The Window Is In Maximized State - Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, resize, controls

Lately I am working on this *personal* app, it's form is without border so the Exit Button, Minimize Button and Maximize button, as well as the option to resize and move the form have been custom added. The app contains several User Controls which perform different functions such as Login, a Control Panel for the app and so on. The issue here is that the User Controls, *which are placed within a panel* (*Anchored* properly, of course) in the main form  are not resizing properly when the window is in a *Maximized* state.

To detail... the app starts at
[this size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQVYC.png) and while it's manually resized in *minimized* state the controls have no issue inheriting it's parent's (the panel) size, 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VHej.png) and this also works if the window is *maximized while the control is visible*, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfpKk.png) however if the window is already in a *maximized* state and I call the control with the designated button the control does not resize, it stays to it's minimum dimensions, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lInUK.png).

At first I thought it may have something to do with the code that resizes the form so I removed everything and made the app with the default windows border and controls, basically set the border Property from *none* to *sizable* but that did nothing. Also I have tried accessing the User Control's parent (the panel) using `this.Parent` and then setting the width and height of the control with `Width = this.Parent.Width` and `Height = this.Parent.Height` but the parent returns `null` for some reason which I am yet to understand. Now, worth mentioning that those user controls are dynamically added (i.e `Login loginForm = new Login();`) to the panel every time the button is clicked and then *Disposed* once the control is left.

I looked all over Google for this but found nothing related and at this point I am out of options. I really want the app to be resizable and must resize properly so if anyone has any solutions I am open to anything.

Thanks anticipated.

Comment: Dexter welcome ! I have no answer, but your problem with restore from maximized sounds familiar, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308987/wpf-window-state-when-restored-from-maximized-gets-stuck-in-odd-state and another topic about anchors in WPF, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188586/how-to-anchor-controls-in-wpf/15425217

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time, but the first link you provided is even longer than what I wrote (or just as long), I tried to provide as much information as possible and make it as short as I could while giving enough detail. 
Sadly neither help, my anchoring works well from what I can tell and I have no Show() method in the code that displays the control. Also my application is not WPF is a Windows Forms Application.

Comment: Ah ! I put the wrong links, your screen prints look WPF-style so I put some WPF links. Can you please submit some code, that is the code of your resize action ? And I assume your user control is the center with DockStyle Fill ? Does it perform its own resize actions ? can you post these too ? Parenting must be assigned before you can use it. Are you sure the Parent property is assigned, in your code or in designer code..

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, for Winforms, I may have an answer.. the key is to use the Resize event of your user control(s), see below. I tested this in Core 3.1 and Net 4.7, you can use an default designer.cs unit with an empty form. It has no issues with resize from maximized state.

My user control for the center app is named CenteredPanel and derived from Panel. Make *sure* you derive your user controls from Panel and call base() on the constructor, else the docking will not work properly.

Also, your question about parenting: it was not needed to use Parent below, but if you really need it, make sure you *assign* it !

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Panel panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4;
        private CenteredPanel panelApp;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
              { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
              { Parent = panel1, Dock = DockStyle.Left, Width = 120, BackColor = Color.FromArgb(60, 60, 60) };
            this.panel3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
              { Parent = panel1, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            this.panel4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
              { Parent = panel3, Dock = DockStyle.Top, Height = 60, BackColor = Color.FromArgb(60, 60, 60) };
            this.panelApp = new WindowsFormsAppCore.CenteredPanel()
              { Parent = panel3, Dock = DockStyle.Fill, BackColor = Color.FromArgb(90, 90, 90) };
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.panel3);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
            this.panel3.Controls.Add(this.panelApp);
            this.panel3.Controls.Add(this.panel4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        }
    }

    public class CenteredPanel : Panel
    {
        Label label1, label2;
        TextBox textbox1;

        public CenteredPanel() : base()
        {
            this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Resizer);
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label()
              { Parent = this, AutoSize = true, Name = "label1", ForeColor =Color.White, Text = "Connectare Administrator" };
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label()
              { Parent = this, AutoSize = true, Name = "label2", ForeColor = Color.White, Text = "Nume de utilizator" };
            this.textbox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
              { Parent = this, AutoSize = true, Name = "textbox1", PasswordChar = '*', Text = "****" };
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textbox1);
        }

        public void Resizer(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Point CenteringAnchor = new Point(Width / 2, Height / 2);
            for (int i=0; i<Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                Control c = Controls[i];
                // put your resizing rules here.. this is a very simple one
                c.Location = new Point(CenteringAnchor.X - c.Width / 2, -40 + i * ((i == 1) ? 40 : 30) + CenteringAnchor.Y - c.Height / 2);
            }
        }
    }
```